# Why is a segmentation fault not reproducible in gdb?

Tags: linux, gdb, googletest, googlemock

I have a situation where I run a number of unit tests and one of them triggers a segmentation fault. The symptom seems related to another test case run roughly 30 test cases prior to the failing one. Obviously there is some dependency between the test cases and I can easily turn on and off the segmentation fault by commenting out the earlier test case. Google Test/Mock 1.6.0 is used as test framework. The test binary is written entirely in C++ (gcc 4.6.3). It is single threaded (unless Google Test creates threads).

However, when I run all test cases in gdb there is no segmentation fault and this is what puzzles me.

What are realistic reasons why there would be a segmentation fault when running a binary in a terminal, but not when running the very same binary through gdb? I guess everything is slightly slower when gdb runs the code, but I don't see how this would affect the outcome.

I just do this to see no fault:

```
gdb MyBinary
run
```

Last lines of terminal printout:

```
[  PASSED  ] 368 tests.
[Inferior 1 (process 28349) exited normally]
```

And this to see the fault:

```
MyBinary
```

Last line of terminal printout:

```
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: You probably won't have any idea until you find the bug. As long as you can reproduce the bug somehow, you shouldn't get too obsessed with the circumstances in which it occurs until you have some reason to think they're important.

Comment: You could try running the unit test under valgrind to see what memory errors it managed to detect.

Comment: BTW, you could limit the `core` dump size to a reasonable figure (e.g. 500Mbytes at least) and run `gdb` post mortem on the `core`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What are realistic reasons why there would be a segmentation fault when running a binary in a terminal, but not when running the very same binary through gdb?

The two most common ones are:

1. GDB disables address space randomization. If you are reading some uninitialized pointer, and that pointer always happens to be `NULL` under GDB, but may not be `NULL` with ASLR.
2. You have a data race, and GDB slows down thread creation to hide that race (GDB has to do a *lot* of work to keep track of all threads).

You can prevent GDB from disabling ASLR with `set disable-randomization off`.

You should probably check your tests using [MemorySanitizer](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/MemorySanitizer.html) and [ThreadSanitizer](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ThreadSanitizer.html).